# Query to aggregate contract line-item values across contracts

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

I have 2 tables in Microsoft Access: Contract_1 & Contract Items

`Contract_1` has columns like: `Contract ID, Contract Value, Date, Committed Prod_ID,` an example of their values will be:

```
1  $100,000  3/5/15 111
```

Contract Items has `Prod ID, Product, Unit Price` an example of their values will be:

```
111  Light Bulb  $5.00
```

They are linked by a One to Many relationship, `Prod ID {PK}` to Committed `Prod_ID` in `Contract_1`.

When I write a query to show a summary of the products and total price, I get

```
Product|             Unit Price|        Quantity|             Total Price|

Light Bulb| $5.00|  2|  $10.00

Light Bulb| $5.00|  3|  $15.00
```

In my data i have 2 Contracts, contract ID 1 and 5, that both purchased light bulbs. But since they are the same product, how can I make them appear as a total of 5 instead of 3 and 2? 
I tried using GROUP BY, but it does not work. My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT [Contract Items].Product, 
[Contract Items].[Unit Price], 
Contract_1.[Actual Qty] AS Quantity, 
[Unit Price]*[Quantity] AS [Total Price]
    FROM [Contract Items] 
    INNER JOIN Contract_1 
ON [Contract Items].[Prod ID]=Contract_1.[Committed Prod_ID]
    GROUP BY  [Contract Items].Product, 
[Contract Items].[Unit Price], 
Contract_1.[Actual Qty], 
[Contract Items].[Quantity];
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need aggregate function SUM, e.g. SUM(Quantity). (Then remove Quantity from GROUP BY list.)

Comment: @jarlh This is what I did. but it still doesnt work 

SELECT [Contract Items].Product, [Contract Items].[Unit Price], Contract_1.[Actual Qty] AS Quantity, [Unit Price]*SUM([Quantity]) AS [Total Price]
FROM [Contract Items] 
INNER JOIN Contract_1 ON [Contract Items].[Prod ID]=Contract_1.[Committed Prod_ID]
GROUP BY  [Contract Items].Product, 
[Contract Items].[Unit Price], 
Contract_1.[Actual Qty];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this(**EDITED**), what @jarlh is saying :

```
 SELECT [Contract Items].Product, 
 [Contract Items].[Unit Price], 
 SUM(Contract_1.[Actual Qty]) AS Quantity, 
 SUM([Contract Items].[Unit Price]*Contract_1.[Actual Qty]) AS [Total Price]
 FROM [Contract Items] 
 INNER JOIN Contract_1 
 ON [Contract Items].[Prod ID]=Contract_1.[Committed Prod_ID]
 GROUP BY  [Contract Items].Product, 
 [Contract Items].[Unit Price];
```

Comment: Hmm, I got an error saying I can't use subqueries, which referred to this line >> SUM([Unit Price]*[Quantity])  :/

Answer (score 0):

In that case first get the count and then do a join and calculate the total price like below

```
SELECT [Contract Items].Product, 
[Contract Items].[Unit Price], 
tab.Quantity, 
[Contract Items].[Unit Price] * tab.[Quantity] AS [Total Price]
FROM [Contract Items] 
INNER JOIN  
(
SELECT Committed Prod_ID,
count(*) as Quantity
FROM Contract_1
GROUP BY Committed Prod_ID
) tab ON [Contract Items].[Prod ID]=tab.[Committed Prod_ID]
```

Comment: When I used that query, I get two of the same products like :
Light Bulb| $5.00|  2|  $10.00

Light Bulb| $5.00|  3|  $15.00